# WPF CefSharp: Session restoring does not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cookies, cefsharp

I have a question.

I develop a WPF application using CefSharp v75.1.141 from NuGet.
The application contains several instances of ChromiumWebBrowser with separate containers cookie cache, etc. where each instance is authorized on the site https://web.whatsapp.com/ under different account. On other sites, session are saved and restored successfully, but not at WhatsApp.

WhatsApp, as I understand it, uses cookies, local storage and file system for authorization.

All this seems to be saved on disk, but authorization is always required after a restart.
I tried many configuration options for Cef, but nothing worked.
But if you use Cef in normal mode (without separate storage), everything works fine.

Browser Initialization Code on app startup:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.RootCachePath = "Cache";
// For FHD+
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
// Initialize cef with the provided settings
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Browser instance setup:

```
if (UID == null)
UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings
{
CachePath = Path.Combine("Cache", UID),
PersistSessionCookies = true,
PersistUserPreferences = true
};
Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://web.whatsapp.com/);
Browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);
```

I really need your help. Ty.

Comment: Please read the known issues section of the release notes https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v75.1.141

There is an upstream problem setting the RootCachePath, try downgrading to version 73.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WhatsApp is really.. kinda special. But there's a solution for your problem.
What you need to do is to give WhatsApp Web App little bit more time to process its stuff. Don't close your app too early (give it about 20-40 seconds to let it finish saving data).